# graphlab installation Dependencies missing in Anaconda

Tags: windows, anaconda, graphlab

I'm trying to install GraphLab on my Windows 10, because I need it for an exams at University.

The problem is that I can't install it with the Launcher.exe and now I'm trying to install it with the command line.

I'm following [this guide](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html) from their official site.

1. Downloaded and installed Anaconda2 4.0.0 - `done it`
2. > Create a new conda environment with Python 2.7.x  conda create -n
   >   gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0

   I've tried to do it, but it ends with this thing:

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Dependencies missing in current win-64 channels:
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl
```

This is my `conda list` output if it helps:

```
alabaster                 0.7.7                    py27_0
anaconda                  4.0.0               np110py27_0
anaconda-client           1.4.0                    py27_0
anaconda-navigator        1.1.0                    py27_0
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py27_1
astropy                   1.1.2               np110py27_0
babel                     2.2.0                    py27_0
backports-abc             0.4                       <pip>
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.4.0.2                   <pip>
backports_abc             0.4                      py27_0
beautifulsoup4            4.4.1                    py27_0
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py27_1
blaze                     0.9.1                    py27_0
bokeh                     0.11.1                   py27_0
boto                      2.39.0                   py27_0
bottleneck                1.0.0               np110py27_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                     vc9_2  [vc9]
cdecimal                  2.3                      py27_1
cffi                      1.5.2                    py27_0
chest                     0.2.3                    py27_0
cloudpickle               0.1.1                    py27_0
clyent                    1.2.1                    py27_0
colorama                  0.3.7                    py27_0
comtypes                  1.1.2                    py27_0
conda                     4.0.5                    py27_0
conda-build               1.20.0                   py27_0
conda-env                 2.4.5                    py27_0
conda-manager             0.3.1                    py27_0
configobj                 5.0.6                    py27_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                    py27_1
cryptography              1.3                      py27_0
curl                      7.45.0                    vc9_1  [vc9]
cycler                    0.10.0                   py27_0
cython                    0.23.4                   py27_0
cytoolz                   0.7.5                    py27_0
dask                      0.8.1                    py27_0
datashape                 0.5.1                    py27_0
decorator                 4.0.9                    py27_0
dill                      0.2.4                    py27_0
docutils                  0.12                     py27_1
enum34                    1.1.2                    py27_0
et-xmlfile                1.0.1                     <pip>
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py27_0
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py27_0
flask                     0.10.1                   py27_1
flask-cors                2.1.2                    py27_0
freetype                  2.5.5                     vc9_0  [vc9]
funcsigs                  0.4                      py27_0
futures                   3.0.3                    py27_0
gevent                    1.1.0                    py27_0
greenlet                  0.4.9                    py27_0
grin                      1.2.1                    py27_2
h5py                      2.5.0               np110py27_4
hdf5                      1.8.15.1                  vc9_4  [vc9]
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py27_0
idna                      2.0                      py27_0
ipaddress                 1.0.14                   py27_0
ipykernel                 4.3.1                    py27_0
ipython                   4.1.2                    py27_1
ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py27_0
ipywidgets                4.1.1                    py27_0
itsdangerous              0.24                     py27_0
jdcal                     1.2                      py27_0
jedi                      0.9.0                    py27_0
jinja2                    2.8                      py27_0
jpeg                      8d                        vc9_0  [vc9]
jsonschema                2.4.0                    py27_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py27_2
jupyter-client            4.2.2                     <pip>
jupyter-console           4.1.1                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.1.0                     <pip>
jupyter_client            4.2.2                    py27_0
jupyter_console           4.1.1                    py27_0
jupyter_core              4.1.0                    py27_0
libpng                    1.6.17                    vc9_1  [vc9]
libsodium                 1.0.3                         0
libtiff                   4.0.6                     vc9_1  [vc9]
llvmlite                  0.9.0                    py27_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py27_0
lxml                      3.6.0                    py27_0
markupsafe                0.23                     py27_1
matplotlib                1.5.1               np110py27_0
menuinst                  1.3.2                    py27_0
mistune                   0.7.2                    py27_0
mkl                       11.3.1                        0
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py27_0
mpmath                    0.19                     py27_0
multipledispatch          0.4.8                    py27_0
nbconvert                 4.1.0                    py27_0
nbformat                  4.0.1                    py27_0
networkx                  1.11                     py27_0
nltk                      3.2                      py27_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py27_0
notebook                  4.1.0                    py27_2
numba                     0.24.0              np110py27_0
numexpr                   2.5                 np110py27_0
numpy                     1.10.4                   py27_0
odo                       0.4.2                    py27_0
openpyxl                  2.3.2                    py27_0
openssl                   1.0.2g                    vc9_0  [vc9]
pandas                    0.18.0              np110py27_0
partd                     0.3.2                    py27_1
path.py                   8.1.2                    py27_1
patsy                     0.4.0               np110py27_0
pep8                      1.7.0                    py27_0
pickleshare               0.5                      py27_0
pillow                    3.1.1                    py27_0
pip                       8.1.1                    py27_1
ply                       3.8                      py27_0
psutil                    4.1.0                    py27_0
py                        1.4.31                   py27_0
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py27_0
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py27_0
pycparser                 2.14                     py27_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py27_3
pyflakes                  1.1.0                    py27_0
pygments                  2.1.1                    py27_0
pyopenssl                 0.15.1                   py27_2
pyparsing                 2.0.3                    py27_0
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py27_5
pyreadline                2.1                      py27_0
pytables                  3.2.2               np110py27_2
pytest                    2.8.5                    py27_0
python                    2.7.11                        4
python-dateutil           2.5.1                    py27_0
pytz                      2016.2                   py27_0
pywin32                   220                      py27_1
pyyaml                    3.11                     py27_3
pyzmq                     15.2.0                   py27_0
qt                        4.8.7                     vc9_7  [vc9]
qtawesome                 0.3.2                    py27_0
qtconsole                 4.2.0                    py27_1
qtpy                      1.0                      py27_0
requests                  2.9.1                    py27_0
rope                      0.9.4                    py27_1
scikit-image              0.12.3              np110py27_0
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np110py27_0
scipy                     0.17.0              np110py27_0
setuptools                20.3                     py27_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py27_0
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py27_0
sip                       4.16.9                   py27_2
six                       1.10.0                   py27_0
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py27_0
sockjs-tornado            1.0.1                    py27_0
sphinx                    1.3.5                    py27_0
sphinx-rtd-theme          0.1.9                     <pip>
sphinx_rtd_theme          0.1.9                    py27_0
spyder                    2.3.8                    py27_1
sqlalchemy                1.0.12                   py27_0
ssl_match_hostname        3.4.0.2                  py27_0
statsmodels               0.6.1               np110py27_0
sympy                     1.0                      py27_0
tables                    3.2.2                     <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                    vc9_0  [vc9]
toolz                     0.7.4                    py27_0
tornado                   4.3                      py27_0
traitlets                 4.2.1                    py27_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py27_0
vs2008_runtime            9.00.30729.1                  0
vs2010_runtime            10.00.40219.1                 0
werkzeug                  0.11.4                   py27_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0
xlrd                      0.9.4                    py27_0
xlsxwriter                0.8.4                    py27_0
xlwings                   0.7.0                    py27_0
xlwt                      1.0.0                    py27_0
zlib                      1.2.8                     vc9_2  [vc9]
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
conda update pip
```

Do this first and all will be resolved. :-p

Answer (score 1):

```
conda update conda
```

This is one of the possible solutions