# Dependencies missing in current win-64 channels

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, command-prompt, graphlab

After the default Graphlab Install executable failed, I'm now trying to install Graphlab using the command prompt. Step-by-step tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html).

When running the line

```
conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
```

I get the following error:

```
    Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
    Fetching package metadata: ....
    Solving package specifications: .
    Error:  Dependencies missing in current win-64 channels:
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py35_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py34_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py27_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
      - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl

    You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

        anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl
```

Yet when I follow the suggestion and run the last line, I get the following error:

```
    usage: anaconda-script.py [-h] [--show-traceback] [--hide-traceback] [-v] [-q]
                      [--color] [--no-color] [-V] [-t TOKEN] [-s SITE]
                      ...
    anaconda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: * mkl
```

I can't seem to find any fix for this anywhere online. Does anyone have an idea how to fix?

Answer (score 4):

```
conda update pip
```

It worked for me, taken from [similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083053/graphlab-installation-dependencies-missing-in-anaconda?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

You can run the command "conda install -c bioninja mkl" and then "conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda".